# Sum of powers of nth root of 1

Tags: complex-numbers

We have $\epsilon \neq 1$ where $\epsilon$ is a solution to $x^n=1$ and we try to evaluate $1 + \epsilon + \epsilon^2 + \epsilon^3 + \dots + \epsilon^{n-1}$. Multiplying this by $\epsilon - 1$, we get $\epsilon^n - 1$ and write the value of the initial expression as $f(\epsilon)={\epsilon^n - 1 \over \epsilon - 1}$. This is equivalent to
$${\left(\cos{2 \pi k \over n} + i \sin{2 \pi k \over n}\right)^n - 1 \over \epsilon - 1} = {1 - 1 \over \epsilon - 1} = 0$$

Is there a quicker way to arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: Your proof is very quick indeed! Why do you think there is a quicker one?

Comment: You don't need to go through $\cos$ and $\sin$.  You defined that $\epsilon^n=1$ so use that.

Comment: It seems to me that this is sufficiently quick! However, I would say that this is the quickest: At a certain point you have to use $ \epsilon^n - 1=0$ of course.

Comment: Intuitively: The $n-$ th roots of unity are the vertices of a regular $n-$ gon. Consider the sum of the vectors form the origin to the vertices.

Comment: Let $S$ be your sum and note that $\epsilon S=S$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Correct, this is the only unnecessary thing in the proof.

Comment: @EmilioNovati The sum of the roots is $0$ , not $1$. The question is about the sum of the powers of one particular root.

Comment: @EmilioNovati This works when $\epsilon$ is a fundamental root of unity, which is not assumed.

Comment: @Did. Good point!  I agree :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  In particular, there's no reason to go through the calculation $\left(\cos{2 \pi k \over n} + i \sin{2 \pi k \over n}\right)^n = 1$.  From the problem statement, we *already* know that $\epsilon^n = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

For each root $ (\epsilon \neq1 )$ of the equation $x^n=1,  \;$  let
$$S_\epsilon=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\epsilon^k.$$

then,  for each one of these $\epsilon$,

$$\epsilon S_\epsilon=S_\epsilon.$$

thus

$$S_\epsilon=0,$$

since $\epsilon\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically...

The center of gravity of the set of vertices of the polygon $\{1, \epsilon, \cdots, \epsilon^{n-1}\}$ is the center of that polygon.  Proof: the polygon is invariant under rotation by $\epsilon$ about the center, so the center of gravity is also inveriant under that rotation.

Comment: This works when $\epsilon$ is a fundamental root of unity. Otherwise a "subpolygon" is involved, whose vertices do not necessarily appear in the anticlockwise order.

Comment: OK, let's say "rotation $\epsilon$".  Then it is really the other solutions again.

Comment: So, we forget geometry? *Schade*...